# LL(1) grammar verification

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

Let `G` be a grammar such that:

```
S -> aBa
B -> bB | \epsilon
```

where `\epsilon` represents the empty string.

After computing `FIRST` and `FOLLOW`, is there a way to tell if `G` is `LL(1)` without resorting to the parsing table?

Comment: I suppose this is homework, so this approach is out of question, but if I had to check this as part of a real problem (especially with a larger grammar), I'd simply feed the grammar to an LL(1) parser generator ;)

Comment: What do you mean by out of question? you're saying I'm wrong? Actually since building a parsing table is somewhat difficult for me, I only wanted to know if there was another way to tell if G is LL(1) Sorry for my lack of knowldge

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework question. If it's homework, using someone else's automated tools to answer it is of course not allowed. In cases where it's allowed, it might very well be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

After computing the `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets for the variables of `G`, you can compute the length 1 lookahead sets `LA(1)` for the variables and rules of `G`. Then `G` is strong `LL(1)` iff the following condition holds:

```
LA(1)(A -> wi) partition LA(1)(A) for each variable A such that A -> wi is a rule.
```

Alternatively, you can prove that `G` is strong `LL(1)` from the definition of a strong `LL(k)` grammar without computing the `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets. This is oftentimes easier and less tedious than computing `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` for small grammars like `G`.

I don't have a book handy, so there might be an error in some of these definitions or computations. But this is how I would approach the problem. Computing the `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets gives:

```
FIRST(1)(S) = trunc(1)({x : S =>* x AND x IN Σ*})
            = trunc(1)({ab^na : n >= 0})
            = {a}

FIRST(1)(B) = trunc(1)({x : B =>* x AND x IN Σ*})
            = trunc(1)({b^n : n >= 0})
            = {ε,b}

FOLLOW(1)(S) = trunc(1)({x : S =>* uSv AND x IN FIRST(1)(v)})
             = trunc(1)({x : x IN FIRST(1)(ε)})
             = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(ε))
             = {ε}

FOLLOW(1)(B) = trunc(1)({x : S =>* uBv AND x IN FIRST(1)(v)})
             = trunc(1)({x : x IN FIRST(1)(a)})
             = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(a))
             = {a}
```

Computing the length 1 lookahead sets for the variables and rules gives:

```
LA(1)(S) = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(S)FOLLOW(1)(S))
         = trunc(1)({a}{ε})
         = trunc(1){a}
         = {a}
LA(1)(B) = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(B)FOLLOW(1)(B))
         = trunc(1)({ε,b}{a})
         = trunc(1){a,b}
         = {a,b}

LA(1)(S -> aBa) = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(a)FIRST(1)(B)FIRST(1)(a)FOLLOW(1)(S))
                = trunc(1){a}
                = {a}
LA(1)(B -> bB)  = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(b)FIRST(1)(B))
                = trunc(1){b} 
                = {b}
LA(1)(B -> ε)   = trunc(1)(FIRST(1)(ε)FOLLOW(1)(b))
                = trunc(1)({ε}{a})
                = {a}
```

Since `LA(1)(B -> ε)` and `LA(1)(B -> bB)` partition `LA(1)(B)` and `LA(1)(S -> aBa)` trivially partitions `LA(1)(S)`, `G` is strong `LL(1)`.

Comment: Can I ask why this response was downvoted? Did I make an error somewhere or provide false information?

Comment: Downvoter here. I downvoted because the question, based on the subject matter, is very likely homework. IMO, your answer is too complete and leaves nothing to do for the OP. I realize this is a contested issue, but I think answers to probable homework questions should not 'give away' everything.